# Mono .net HTTP 500. Error

Tags: ubuntu, mono, apache2

i have been trying to get Mod Mono to run on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS with apache2.2.22

ive been tring for two weeks now and i can only get a error 500 page.
can anyone help me here?

### here is my Stack Trace

Error running vbnc: Cannot find the specified file

Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

Stack Trace:

System.SystemException: Error running vbnc: Cannot find the specified file
  at Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeCompiler.CompileFromFileBatch (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromFileBatch (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath, System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GenerateAssembly (System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder abuilder, System.Web.Compilation.BuildProviderGroup group, System.Web.VirtualPath vp, Boolean debug) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BuildInner (System.Web.VirtualPath vp, Boolean debug) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.Build (System.Web.VirtualPath vp) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath, System.Type requiredBaseType) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.UI.PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance (System.String virtualPath, System.String inputFile, System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.String requestType, System.String url, System.String path) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.GetHandler (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.String url, Boolean ignoreContextHandler) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.GetHandler (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.String url) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication+c__Iterator6.MoveNext () [0x00000] in :0

Version information: Mono Runtime Version: 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.1

---

My error logs don't say anything for mod_mono

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you are trying to run code written using visual basic. For that, you need the `vbnc` compiler installed. Looking at the ubuntu packages, `vbnc` does not seem to be available in 12.04, only in 12.10 (in the [mono-vbnc package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/mono-vbnc)). Also note that vbnc only supports .NET 2.0 as far as I know.

If you do not need VB support, you might already be good to go, just test using a C# page.
Otherwise you could upgrade your whole distribution, install backported mono packages or install mono from source.

Comment: the Page Language I was trying to run was C#. but none the less i installed the mono-vbnc package and now they are loading.   Thank you Jester

Comment: I think in ubuntu 12.04 it was called "mono-basic"